# Why $E$ should be written like this?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The question is given below and a part of its answer:

> [image]
>   [image]

But I do not understand why $E$ should be written like this?
Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The text says "can" not "should" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $x\in E$ iff $\{f_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy, that is, iff
$$ \forall\epsilon>0\colon \exists m\colon \forall i\ge m\colon\forall j\ge m\colon|f_i(x)-f_j(x)|<\epsilon$$
Clearly, it suffices to consider only $\epsilon$ of the form $\frac 1n$, i.e., 
$$\begin{align}x\in E&\iff \forall n\colon \exists m\colon \forall i\ge m\colon\forall j\ge m\colon|f_i(x)-f_j(x)|<\frac 1n\\
&\iff \forall n\colon \exists m\colon \forall i\ge m\colon\forall j\ge m\colon x\in\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}\\
&\iff \forall n\colon \exists m\colon \forall i\ge m\colon x\in\bigcap_{j=m}^\infty\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}\\
&\iff \forall n\colon \exists m\colon  x\in\bigcap_{i=m}^\infty\bigcap_{j=m}^\infty\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}\\
&\iff \forall n\colon   x\in\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{i=m}^\infty\bigcap_{j=m}^\infty\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}\\
&\iff x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{i=m}^\infty\bigcap_{j=m}^\infty\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}\\
\end{align}$$

---

Note however that it is not *fully* trivial that the individual $\{\,y\in\Bbb R\mid |f_i(y)-f_j(y)|<\tfrac 1n\,\}$ are measurable - this may depend on which results you already have available.
Thus it *might* be more advisable to write
$$ E=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{a,b\in\Bbb Q\atop a<b<a+\frac1n}\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{i=m}^\infty f_i^{-1}([a,b])$$
Do you see why *that* would be allowed?

Comment: I was working on the same answer +1